# JQuery .on('click',...) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

When the user presses on the link, I want to insert HTML after the element with class `jstore-js-detailLink`.

My attempt doesn't seem to work:

```
<a href="" class="jstore-js-detailLink">hello</a>
<div class="lsp-popup-item-name"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a[class^=".jstore-js-detailLink"]', function() {
    jQuery('<div id="stars-block" class="stars">'+
           '<div id="reviewStars-input">'+
           '<input id="star-4" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>'+
           '<label title="gorgeous" for="star-4"></label>'+
           '<input id="star-3" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>'+
           '<label title="good" for="star-3"></label>'+
           '<input id="star-2" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>'+
           '<label title="regular" for="star-2"></label>'+
           '<input id="star-1" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>'+
           '<label title="poor" for="star-1"></label>'+
           '<input id="star-0" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>'+
           '<label title="bad" for="star-0"></label>'+
           '<br>'+
           '</div>'+
           '</div>').insertAfter(".lsp-popup-item-name");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the `.` in your `class` attribute selector:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a[class^="jstore-js-detailLink"]', function(){

}
```

The above code is called an [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). It adds a `click` handler to all the `anchror` elements in the DOM which have a class starting with `jstore-js-detailLink`.

You add the `.` only when you are using a [Class Selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). In your case, the below code will also work:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a.jstore-js-detailLink', function() {
    ..........
}
```

or

You can simplify it to:

```
$("a.jstore-js-detailLink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...........
});
```

The `e.preventDefault()` will stop the anchor from acting as a link and jumping to the top of the page or adding a `#` at the end of the URL.

Comment: thanx
i'm already use this :
jQuery(document).on("click", ".jstore-js-detailLink", function() { });

Answer (score -1):

Change selector to `class^="jstore-js-detailLink"` and add `event.preventDefault();` into event handler.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a[class^="jstore-js-detailLink"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('<div id="stars-block" class="stars">'+
    '<div id="reviewStars-input">'+
    '<input id="star-4" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>'+
    '<label title="gorgeous" for="star-4"></label>'+
    '<input id="star-3" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>'+
    '<label title="good" for="star-3"></label>'+
    '<input id="star-2" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>'+
    '<label title="regular" for="star-2"></label>'+
    '<input id="star-1" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>'+
    '<label title="poor" for="star-1"></label>'+
    '<input id="star-0" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>'+
    '<label title="bad" for="star-0"></label>'+
    '<br>'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>').insertAfter(".lsp-popup-item-name")
    });
 </script>
```